# Capture event when not Browser back/forward click

Tags: javascript, dom, events, dom-events

I have captured browser back and forward event on JavaScript

```
window.onpopstate = this.getBackForwardEvents
```

And then I'm making some variable `boolean` value true

```
_fwdBckButtonVar = false;

getBackForwardEvents(e){
    _fwdBckButtonVar = true;
}
```

Now when browser back or forward button is clicked, I'm making `_fwdBckButtonVar`  as `true`.

How do I capture event which is not **window.onpopstate** so that I have make it as `false`

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: i have a if else condition to check if the click is happening from browser back/forward click

Comment: if you initialized your _fwdBckButtonVar to false, and check _fwdBckButtonVar it makes the job.

Comment: yes, i want to do it when `window.onpopstate` should not trigger or the else condition on `window.onpopstate`

Comment: you can make a wile (true) and break when _window.onpopstate_